# How to get Fibonacci number with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Fibonacci {

    int fab=0;
    int fab1=1;
    public int fabi(int n){
        if(n>=1){
            System.out.println(n);
            return fabi(fab-1)+fabi(fab1-2);    
        }
        else
            return 1;

    }
}
```

I have some logical issue in code when I am using recursion method.

Comment: So you already solved this task with `for` and you generally know how the algo should work ... can you know explain how you came up with `fab-1` and `fab1-2`? Those variables make no sense to me and that you don't change `n` makes even less sense to me. Maybe you can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function :

```
int fib(int n) 
{ 
if (n <= 1) 
   return n; 
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
}
```